# Query Designer in Visual studio returns <Binary> column and ssrs text box returns #Error

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, type-conversion, crystal-reports-2008

I have several columns selected in my dataset. Some of which have GROUP_CONCAT like below where the separator is a line break.

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(table.table_column2 SEPARATOR "\n") AS column2
    FROM
    table
```

the result for column2 in the Query Designer of the dataset gives the word **Binary** surrounded by chevrons and the textbox on my rdl report gives me **#Error**.

I understand that it's because column2 is data type decimal(5,0) and the group_concat is probably turning it into a string and the report doesn't like it.

Any ideas what I can do to convert this in the VB expression for the text box?

> =Fields!column2.Value

Comment: Managed to resolve. I amended the code on the group_concat. `GROUP_CONCAT(cast(table.table_column2 as char)
        SEPARATOR ",\n") AS column2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the CAST Function within the code has worked

```
GROUP_CONCAT(cast(table.table_column2 as char) SEPARATOR ",\n") AS column2
```